# JavaFX have scroll-bar transparent for all elements (scoll pane, text area, etc)

Tags: css, javafx, scrollbar

What I am lookig for is a scoll-bar similar to IntelliJ IDE:

- track fully transparent
- no buttons
- thumb has partial transparency
- scroll goes up/down untill the very end of the track

[image: IntelliJ example]

The only way I could do this so far is by having this code, but this undecorates my stage - which I do not want to have and it looks more like a workaround than actual control over the scroll-bar. Going with this solution will require a massive change and apply everywhere solid backgrounds, just because the root has changed. Code so far:

Main

```
primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
root.getScene().setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

CSS

```
* {
    -fx-background: transparent;
}

.scroll-pane {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

Code yields (blue background is desktop wallpaper, I only want this to be transparent inside the scene boundaries - not as in the image below)

[image: Current code output]

---

### * **UPDATE**

@john16384 thanks for your input. Based on your example I've tried several variants, sadly not very satisfactory. What happens is what you mentioned, the scrollpane reserves an area for the scrollbars having a different background. See attached examples (scrollbars are green). If I apply barPolicy to never the scrollbars dissapear entirely.

[image: fx1]
[image: fx2]

I might be inclied to consider a different approach, like having a pane or vbox and add scrollbars to it, yet so far I could not find a good example where these could be customised.

Answer (score 3):

You can make scroll bars tracks transparent pretty easily:

```
.scroll-bar .track {
  -fx-fill: transparent;
}
```

The buttons you cannot remove, unless you use your own skin:

```
.scroll-bar {
   -fx-skin: "hs.mediasystem.util.javafx.control.MinimalScrollBarSkin";
}
```

Finally, the IntelliJ screenshot has the contents of the scroll-pane show through the scroll-bar.  Now that is a bit trickier, as the scroll bar will still reserve space and the background would be it's parent, not the content of the `ScrollPane`.

You could only achieve that by writing your own `ScrollPane` (subclass it, and in its `layoutChildren` do custom positioning of the content and overlap the transparent scrollbars over the content).

I donot have an example for that, but it should be possible to achieve.

Anyway, here is the code for the MinimalScrollBarSkin (there might be easier ways to achieve it, but this worked for me):

```
package hs.mediasystem.util.javafx.control;

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.NumberBinding;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.control.Skin;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

/**
 * Scrollbar skin without increment/decrement buttons.
 */
public class MinimalScrollBarSkin implements Skin<ScrollBar> {

  private ScrollBar scrollBar;
  private Region group;
  private Rectangle track = new Rectangle();
  private Rectangle thumb = new Rectangle();

  public MinimalScrollBarSkin(final ScrollBar scrollBar) {
    this.scrollBar = scrollBar;

    this.group = new Region() {
      NumberBinding range = Bindings.subtract(scrollBar.maxProperty(), scrollBar.minProperty());
      NumberBinding position = Bindings.divide(Bindings.subtract(scrollBar.valueProperty(), scrollBar.minProperty()), range);

      {
        // Children are added unmanaged because for some reason the height of the bar keeps changing
        // if they're managed in certain situations... not sure about the cause.
        getChildren().addAll(track, thumb);

        track.setManaged(false);
        track.getStyleClass().add("track");

        thumb.setManaged(false);
        thumb.getStyleClass().add("thumb");

        scrollBar.orientationProperty().addListener(obs -> setup());

        setup();
      }

      private void setup() {
        track.widthProperty().unbind();
        track.heightProperty().unbind();

        if(scrollBar.getOrientation() == Orientation.HORIZONTAL) {
          track.relocate(0, -16);
          track.widthProperty().bind(scrollBar.widthProperty());
          track.setHeight(16);
        }
        else {
          track.relocate(-16, 0);
          track.setWidth(16);
          track.heightProperty().bind(scrollBar.heightProperty());
        }

        thumb.xProperty().unbind();
        thumb.yProperty().unbind();
        thumb.widthProperty().unbind();
        thumb.heightProperty().unbind();

        if(scrollBar.getOrientation() == Orientation.HORIZONTAL) {
          thumb.relocate(0, -16);
          thumb.widthProperty().bind(Bindings.max(16, scrollBar.visibleAmountProperty().divide(range).multiply(scrollBar.widthProperty())));
          thumb.setHeight(16);
          thumb.xProperty().bind(Bindings.subtract(scrollBar.widthProperty(), thumb.widthProperty()).multiply(position));
        }
        else {
          thumb.relocate(-16, 0);
          thumb.setWidth(16);
          thumb.heightProperty().bind(Bindings.max(16, scrollBar.visibleAmountProperty().divide(range).multiply(scrollBar.heightProperty())));
          thumb.yProperty().bind(Bindings.subtract(scrollBar.heightProperty(), thumb.heightProperty()).multiply(position));
        }
      }

      @Override
      protected double computeMaxWidth(double height) {
        if(scrollBar.getOrientation() == Orientation.HORIZONTAL) {
          return Double.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        return 16;
      }

      @Override
      protected double computeMaxHeight(double width) {
        if(scrollBar.getOrientation() == Orientation.VERTICAL) {
          return Double.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        return 16;
      }
    };
  }

  @Override
  public void dispose() {
    scrollBar = null;
    group = null;
  }

  @Override
  public Node getNode() {
    return group;
  }

  @Override
  public ScrollBar getSkinnable() {
    return scrollBar;
  }
}
```

### Update

It is possible to show the scroll bar in the way you want it.  Here is a screenshot from my application, where I made the scroll thumb 96 pixels wide (the bar is still 16 pixels):

[image]

As you can see, the content of the pane shows through the thumb.  I'm not sure why you are getting the gray background reserved area.  It shouldn't be there.

I looked through the styles I have related to the scroll-bar or scroll-pane, and maybe it is one of these that you still need (I suspect the last one, that sets the scroll-pane to transparent):

```
.scroll-bar
{
  -fx-skin: "hs.mediasystem.util.javafx.control.MinimalScrollBarSkin";
  -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.scroll-bar .track
{
  -fx-stroke-width: 1;
  -fx-stroke: -c-dark-glass;
  -fx-arc-width: 16px;
  -fx-arc-height: 16px;
  -fx-fill: transparent;
}

.scroll-bar .thumb
{
  -fx-fill: -c-glass;
  -fx-arc-width: 16px;
  -fx-arc-height: 16px;
}

.list-view,
.scroll-pane,
.scroll-pane > .viewport
{
  -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: With a bit of delay, but thanks @john16384 for your guidance. See my updated post.

Comment: Updated this post, because I think what you want can be achieved now (I didn't realize it was already working in my own app).

Comment: Thanks @john16384, your application looks great, I would like to achieve something similar, in my case there are 3 cases: text area, image view and general pane scrolling. I will have a look this evening and see if I can remove/hide the reserved area and I'll come back (and I'll update the post with my test .fxml file and .css used).

Comment: Hello @john16384, thanks for your effort. I had several attempts at this, and no luck so far - I still have a few more tests in mind.

Comment: I'll see if I can wip up a minimal app that does this

Comment: Thanks @john16384, we can use git, post here, or which ever option you see fit.

Comment: Looks like the scroll-pane I use has its own skin, that puts scroll-bars where I want them (and doesn't reserve space for them).  Side effect is they're not clickable (no issue for me, application is not mouse controlled).  I'll see if I can still modify an example.

Answer (score 0):

john16384's answer is perfect, except the scroll thumb cannot be move by mouse or touch, so i add this function to it. 
PS: i also change the scroll bar width 16 to a valuable which able to define by css but its out of topic

```
        this.group = new Region() {
            private double preDragThumbPos;
            private Point2D dragStart;

            final NumberBinding range = Bindings.subtract(scrollBar.maxProperty(), scrollBar.minProperty());
            final NumberBinding position = Bindings.divide(Bindings.subtract(scrollBar.valueProperty(), scrollBar.minProperty()), this.range);

            {
                // Children are added unmanaged because for some reason the height of the bar keeps changing
                // if they're managed in certain situations... not sure about the cause.
                this.getChildren().addAll(MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.track, MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.thumb);

                MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.track.setManaged(false);
                MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.track.getStyleClass().add("track");

                MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.thumb.setManaged(false);
                MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.thumb.getStyleClass().add("thumb");

                scrollBar.orientationProperty().addListener(obs -> this.setup());

                MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.thumb.setOnMousePressed((mouseEvent) -> {
                    if (mouseEvent.isSynthesized()) {
                        mouseEvent.consume();
                    } else {
                        if (MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.getSkinnable().getMax() > MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.getSkinnable().getMin()) {
                            dragStart = MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.thumb.localToParent(mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY());
                            double value = Utils.clamp(MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.getSkinnable().getMin(), MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.getSkinnable().getValue(), MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.getSkinnable().getMax());
                            preDragThumbPos = (value - MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.getSkinnable().getMin()) / (MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.getSkinnable().getMax() - MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.getSkinnable().getMin());
                            mouseEvent.consume();
                        }

                    }
                });

                MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.thumb.setOnMouseDragged((mouseEvent) -> {
                    if (mouseEvent.isSynthesized()) {
                        mouseEvent.consume();
                    } else {
                        if (MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.getSkinnable().getMax() > MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.getSkinnable().getMin()) {
                            if (this.trackLength() > this.thumbLength()) {
                                Point2D pos = MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.thumb.localToParent(mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY());
                                if (dragStart == null) {
                                    dragStart = MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.thumb.localToParent(mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY());
                                }

                                double value = MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.getSkinnable().getOrientation() == Orientation.VERTICAL ? pos.getY() - dragStart.getY() : pos.getX() - this.dragStart.getX();
                                double change = preDragThumbPos + value / (this.trackLength() - this.thumbLength());
                                double newValue = change * (MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.getSkinnable().getMax() - MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.getSkinnable().getMin()) + MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.getSkinnable().getMin();
                                if (!Double.isNaN(newValue)) {
                                    MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.getSkinnable().setValue(boundedSize(MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.getSkinnable().getMin(), newValue, MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.getSkinnable().getMax()));
                                }
                            }
                            mouseEvent.consume();
                        }
                    }
                });

                this.setup();
            }

            private double trackLength() {
                return MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.getSkinnable().getOrientation() == Orientation.VERTICAL ? MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.track.getHeight() : MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.track.getWidth();
            }

            private double thumbLength() {
                return MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.getSkinnable().getOrientation() == Orientation.VERTICAL ? MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.thumb.getHeight() : MinimalScrollBarSkin.this.thumb.getWidth();
            }

            private double boundedSize(double min, double value, double max) {
                return Math.min(Math.max(value, min), Math.max(min, max));
            }

            private void setup() { ... } 
      }
```

> @4673_j's update

scrollpane will get the scrollbar(not skin)'s pref width/ height when it places it content, so set the pref width/height to 1 or 0 (depend on your track style) in our skin will fix the problem.
For example, modify the setup function to:

```
        if (this.scrollBar.getOrientation() == Orientation.HORIZONTAL) {
            this.track.relocate(0, -size);
            this.track.widthProperty().bind(this.scrollBar.widthProperty());
            this.track.setHeight(size);
            this.getSkinnable().setPrefHeight(track.getStrokeWidth());
        } else {
            this.track.relocate(-size, 0);
            this.track.setWidth(size);
            this.track.heightProperty().bind(this.scrollBar.heightProperty());
            this.getSkinnable().setPrefWidth(track.getStrokeWidth());
        }
```